# formal definition of quadratic subfield

Tags: galois-theory

I am looking for the formal definition of a quadratic subfield of a field $E$. Are they subfields $K$ of $E$ such that $[E:K]=$2?

Here is the context:

I have the polynomial $f(x)= x^4-2x^2+2$. Let $E$ be its splitting field over $\mathbb{Q}$. I was able to determine that $G=\text{Gal}(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong D_8$. I now need to find all the quadratic subfields of $E$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. By the fundamental theorem of Galois thery $[E:K]=[E:E^{H}]=|H|.$

So am I looking for the subgroups of $G=D_8$ of order $2$? And then I would apply $E^H$ to the subgroups $H$ in order to find my quadratic subfields?

I am very confused.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quadratic subfield of $E$ is a subfield $K$ of $E$ that is quadratic, which means that $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$. Because $[E:\Bbb{Q}]=|D_8|=8$ it follows that then $[E:K]=4$, so if $K=E^H$ then $|H|=4$.

So you are looking for subgroups of $D_8$ of order $4$.